# Imprimir en Genexus

Tags: genexus, chrome, imprimir

Quiero agregar un boton que imprima la ventana actual abierta en sistema como pdf, como lo hago, debe mostrar ventana de vista previa de Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías hacer agregando un Textblock y un botón.

En el evento Start agregas el siguiente código:

```
Textblock.Format = 1
Textblock.Visible = 0
```

y en el botón:

```
Textblock.Caption = '<script> window.print(); </script>'
```